# Changes in Xcode: format specifier %p returns <ptr> instead of hexadecimal value

Tags: xcode, xcode7, format-specifiers

I recently upgraded to Xcode7 and my output changed when using %p format-specifier. When I run the code (below):

```
IOLog("%s[%p]::%s()\n", getName(), this, \_\_FUNCTION\_\_);
```

i get:

com_MyCompany_MyDriver[< ptr>]::init()

Using Xcode6 i get:

com_MyCompany_MyDriver[0xffffff8015c49a00]::init()

Under Xcode6 I get a real address.  Under Xcode7 I get 'ptr'.  What changed from 6 to 7?  Why does %p give such an abstract string instead of the real address?

Comment: What is the type of `this`?

Answer (score 1):

System Integrity Protection is protecting kernel addresses by replacing them with '< ptr>'.

Comment: Any way or OS level developer setting to get around this..? I think I remember overhearing something in one of the WWDC videos..